# Looking for a proof of the (general) Salem-Zygmund theorem

Tags: reference-request, descriptive-set-theory, trigonometric-series

I'm looking for a proof of the general Salem-Zygmund theorem, as stated in page 38 of [this](http://www.math.caltech.edu/~kechris/papers/uniqueness.pdf) paper.

I've been searching everywhere for a complete proof, but the only reference I've been able to find is the one given in that same paper, which is [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/270566193X), but sadly I don't read french.

Does anyone know where can I find a proof in english (or spanish)? Something reasonably self-contained would be ideal, or with a more abundant bibliography.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is proved starting on page 90 ($\S4$ of Chapter III) of

> [MR0953784 (90a:42008)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=953784). Alexander S. Kechris and Alain Louveau. **Descriptive set theory and the structure of sets of uniqueness**. London Mathematical Society Lecture Note Series, 128. Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 1987. viii+367 pp. ISBN: 0-521-35811-6.

(The link is to the review at MathSciNet by Howard Becker, it requires a subscription to MathReviews.)

Comment: Awesome, I'll start to work through the proof. Than you very much!

Comment: The whole theory is very pretty. Enjoy!